# How to sendFile from directory if route params match the file name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a directory ./Logs where i am logging files from server and also displaying to the client all file names, Now each file has download option from client so when user call download method i am sending file name to the server route as param and look for file in provided path using forEach on ./Logs directory i am able to get file name that is coming from client and able to print as `data` so till here its working , Now i see the error path must be absolute , Any idea how can i send matched file to the client for download ?

angularFactory.js

```
 getFile:function(file_name){
                return $http.get("/file?file_name="+file_name);
            }
```

app.js

```
    app.get('/file', function (req, res) {
    var dir = './ditLogs';
    var root = path.resolve('./ditLogs');
    var fileName = req.query.file_name;
    var data;
    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, items) {
        items.forEach(function(file){
            if(fileName === file){
                data = file;
                console.log('DATA',data);
                res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + data);
                res.sendFile(data, {root: root});
               // res.sendFile(path.resolve(dir + '/' + data));
               // res.sendFile(data, {root: root});
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
 });
```

error

```
  throw new TypeError('path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile');
^
```

Comment: If you're using Express,  you should probably add that as a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [path.resolve](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_path) to get the absolute path of the file or specify a starting path with the [root](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) option

```
if(fileName === file){
    data = file;
    console.log('DATA',data)
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(path + '/' + data));
}
```

or

```
var root = path.resolve('./Logs');
/* ....... */
if(fileName === file){
    data = file;
    console.log('DATA',data)        
    res.sendFile(data, {root: root});
}
```

Your paths are not absolute (ej: `./Logs/log1.txt` is not the same than `/my/path/to/Logs/log1.txt`) hence the error.

To make the browser prompt the user with a dialog use `res.setHeader` and a `Content-Disposition` header.

```
var root = path.resolve('./Logs');
/* ....... */
if(fileName === file){
    data = file;
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + data);       
    res.sendFile(data, {root: root});
}
```

Comment: this is sending data from the file , i want to send whole file so user can  download it from client, is it possible ?

Comment: @hussain In my code `data` is a string with the file name just like you wrote it in your code. The first parameter in `res.sendFile(path)` is a file path including a file name like `/my/path/to/Logs/log1.txt`, not the contents of the file. Try the code.

Comment: yes i tried that in response i received content of the file not the file itself

Comment: @hussain You mean you want the browser to prompt the user with a save dialog to store the file in his computer?

Comment: yes i edited my question according to your code here i am confuse on dir vs path module so i changed varaibles, yes i want browser to prompt the user to save the file.

Comment: sorry to say but still not prompting the dialog, question edited

Comment: @hussain This is because in the client side you need to call `$window.open('download')` instead of using the `$http` service. Do not edit your question with my answer, it will be very confusing for anyone trying to read and understand your problem later. Remember that someone else might have the same problem than you.

Comment: Thanks for the help i appreciate your time, let me see client side

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the static middleware?

```
app.use('/file', express.static('Logs'));
```

URLs would then map http://yoursite.com/file/somefile.txt to ./Logs/somefile.txt

Comment: Hussain didn't mention that he uses express.

Comment: He didn't, but the use of app.get() and the rest of his code strongly implies it.

Comment: @Paul i am using express i added code as you mentioned using app.use but its throwing 404 on client side.

Comment: Can  you show the updated code, perhaps after the original code?  From what you've written it may be that the client is still asking for the previous URL pattern.